# Excel Macro using Jacob

Tags: java, jacob

Is it possible to run a Excel macro using java, placed in a server which does not have Microsoft Excel installed?.

I have written a code using Java and Jacob - Java Com Bridge, which works fine in machines which has Excel installed.

Comment: Did you try running the same java code in the server? If you tried that, you would have find the answer by your self.

Comment: I tried running it in server, got the error 'Can't get object clsid from progid'. Then modified the code to use clsid for Excel, now i get the error 'com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't find moniker'.

Comment: No you can't. Excel macros require Excel. This seems readily apparent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand first that purpose of JACOB is to connect java with windows component who exposes their operations via COM interface. That means you can only operate on those applications which are installed in the server and have implemented COM interface. For instance : MS Excel, MS Word, Adobe etc

Answer (score -1):

As you tried, the answer is no. No excel means no Java Com Bridge.

Comment: No it doesn't. It means no Excel to bridge *to.* You could still bridge to other COM components if they're installed.